# R switch() / How can I make several strings lead to the same code?

Tags: r

`arg` can take several different string-values `"A", "B", "three", "four"`.

I want to use a `switch()` command to execute one batch of code for `arg == "A" || arg == "B"` and another for `arg == "three" || arg == "four"`. But I don't want to type everything twice like:

```
switch(arg,
       A = {#code block 1
       },
       B = {#code block 1
       },

       three = {#code block 2
       },
       four = {#code block 2
       }
)
```

I could use

```
ifelse (arg %in% list("A", "B"), #code block 1,
        if (arg %in% list("three", "four")) #code block 2
)
```

but is there a nicer way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
switch(switch(arg, B='A', four='three', arg),
       A = {#code block 1
       },
       three = {#code block 2
       }

)
```

Comment: V. neat.  Wordsmyth: While this is short and perfectly serviceable, I think using `%in%` for your multiple conditions would be more obvious to the casual reader, and in that sense is nicer if anyone has to look at your code. You should be able to use `arg %in% list...` where you would use `arg==arg1||arg==arg2`